# MFC Feature Pack Bug? Ribbon Based GUI does not restore after hibernation (sleep mode)

Tags: c++, hibernate, mfc-feature-pack

I've forced with a possible <del>bug</del> feature of MFC Feature Pack under Windows Vista. It can be easily recreated:

1. Create a new SDI app using MFC Feature Pack (with Ribbon based interface). You can also add some floating panels if you want;
2. Do not change anything, just build a Release;
3. Close the Visual Studio, run the application and turn your computer into Sleep Mode (Hibernation).
4. Restore the computer from the sleep mode and you will see that the application did not restore well: it does not correctly display window's caption; it is impossible to increase the window size (it cuts the frame), etc.

Did anyone forced with this behavior?

I'm using Windows Vista Business SP2 and getting the same behavior on my desktop and laptop. Unfortunately did not tested under XP or another platform.

PS: I've solved the mentioned problem for toolbar based application by switching the visual style to any other and back on receiving WM_POWERBROADCAST. But the trick does not work for ribbon based application.

Comment: If you think it's a bug, better send it directly to microsofts bugtracker. (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/clr/thread/e55d8ce6-ad64-4414-ac83-c70872fecc31)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, thanks for the tip, and looking for it I found a solution, I only tried it in an app with toolbar, I have not tried it in Ribbon, if it works in ribbon confirm me please.

What works for me:

```
  // add to class CMainFrame :

    UINT CMainFrame::OnPowerBroadcast(UINT nPowerEvent, UINT nEventData)
    {       
        // Comment "default return" and return true
        //return CMDIFrameWndEx::OnPowerBroadcast(nPowerEvent, nEventData);
        return true;
    }
```

Source: [msdn forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/88b4bfe4-782a-4a0d-a042-e38be2c56544/mfc-feature-packs-visual-manager-and-sleep-problem-bug?forum=vcgeneral).